# Payment Method and Discount elements query by ID in Twig

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, query, payment-methods, discounts

In Craft 2, is it possible to query a specific element by ID in Twig?  They aren't mentioned in the docs.

I was trying things like these but without success:

```
{{ craft.commerce.paymentMethods.id(1).name }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commerce 1:

```
{% set paymentMethod = null %}
{% for pm in craft.commerce.paymentMethods %}
    {% if pm.id == 2 %}{% set paymentMethod = pm %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ paymentMethod.name }}
```

Commerce 2:

`{{ craft.commerce.gateways.getGatewayById(2).name }}`

Comment: For Commerce 1, it only seems to work for payment methods that are available for checkout.  Is there a way to query methods that are not available for checkout?

Comment: Unfortunately not